# File reading in map with an multi-dimensional array as the value type

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14

i'm trying to read from a file in a map with a multi-dimensional array. I wrote already the code and it seems like its working but if i look at the map content its wrong. Is there a problem with my code and is there a better solution with bitset without to change the multi dimensional array to a bitset?
File content looks like this:

```
a
00000000
00110000
00000011
00100000
00000000
00001000
01000000
00011000
6
11111000
00011000
...
```

and so on
my code without exceptions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>


using namespace std;

void main()
{

map <char, array<array<int, 8>, 8>> tablemap;   
string sign, line;
ifstream file;

source.open("file.txt");

    while (getline(source, sign))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            getline(source, line);

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                tablemap[sign.at(0)][i][j] = static_cast<int>(line.at(j));

            }                                       
        }
    }
    source.close();     
}
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess, the data you read ends up being e.g. `48` and `49`, instead of `0` and `1` (respectively).

That's because `static_cast<int>(line.at(j))` doesn't convert a numeric character into its integer equivalent. Instead you just get the integer equivalent of the *encoded* character (which you don't need a `static_cast` to get, really).

If you look at [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) (ASCII being the most common encoding) you will see that the character `'1'` will have the integer value `49`. If you look a little closer you will see that all the digits are following each other, which means that to get the integer `1` from the character `'1'`, you can simply subtract `'0'` from your character. As in `line[j] - '0'`.

So what you should do is

```
tablemap[sign.at(0)][i][j] = line[j] - '0';
```

<sub>Note: This digit to integer arithmetic is specified in the C++ specification, but for *digits only*. Even if it's possible to do for ASCII-encoded letters it's not part of the C++ standard.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Change the static cast by a call to std::stoi as shown in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol